# Hdiutil files case sensitivity changing in ISO

Tags: macos, hdiutil

Running this command to create an `iso` on `macOS`:

```
hdiutil makehybrid -o ~/Desktop/test.iso ~/Documents/files/ -iso
```

When mounting the `iso` all files in the directory are in *upper case*.

How can I stop case-sensitivity from changing with this command?

Comment: Maybe try changing `-iso` to `-joliet`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The command required `-iso` and `-joliet` but it worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project. Write the answer up and mark it as correct if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Mark Setchell: the addition of `-joliet`:

```
hdiutil makehybrid -o ~/Desktop/test.iso ~/Documents/files/ -joliet -iso
```

Maintains case sensitivity when creating the `iso`.